# Как правильно организовать смену состояний (сцен) при паттерне Entity Component System?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, state, ecs

Разрабатываю игру используя концепцию ECS. За основу взята библиотека entt. Имеется один глобальный реестр, в котором хранятся сущности с компонентами на них. Возникла необходимость смены состояний игры (заставка, главное меню, основной геймплей, экран результатов и т.д.). Это некие сцены в которых имеется свой набор сущностей и систем, которые их обрабатывают. И появилось непонимание, как правильно организовать процесс смены этих состояний(сцен) имея при этом единый реестр. Получается мне нужно при переходе из сцены 1 в сцену 2, удалять сущности сцены 1 и останавливать специфичные только для нее системы. А это значит мне нужно хранить (помимо реестра) в сцене массив созданных сущностей, что бы пробегать по нему и удалять при выгрузке сцены из памяти. Не уверен что это хорошее решение. Может есть какие то лучшие практики?

Comment: Не знаю как у вас в Юнити/ECS, но уничтожать-создавать сцены каждый раз звучит несколько накладным. Почему бы не ввести флаг по типу Active/Visible и рисовать/обновлять только ту сцену, у которой он выставлен? Или же завести единственный рисующийся/обновляемый нод и в нем держать ссылку на текущую сцену?

Comment: У меня чистый с++ и библиотека entt, не Unity. У меня есть допустим сцена с логотипом игры и сцена основного гемплея, которая должна запуститься сразу после показа логотипа. Есть универсальная система, которая рисует все, у чего есть DrawableComponent. Получается я создаю сущность "логотип", вешаю на него DrawableComponent. Система "отрисовки" графики рисует логотип основаваясь на данных из компонента, система отслеживания времени ведет отсчет и по истечении скажем 5 секунд переключает сцену на основную с геймплеем.

Comment: И вот тут, что бы логотип пропал я, по идее должен удалить из реестра сущностей сущность "логотип" и создать новые сущности, которые нужны для игрового процесса. Это единственный сценарий который мне приходит в голову для ситуации, когда имеется один глобальный реестр. И тут проблема в том, что если сущностей очень много и все они создаются или уничтожаются в разных местах приложения и в разное время, то встает вопрос хранить где то массив с id тех сущностей, которые активны в данный момент.

Comment: В том варианте, о котором вы говорите, если я правильно понял, сцены это какой то изолированный объект, который хранит в себе все состояние и допустим метод update и переключение просто ставит указатель на активную сцену у которой вызывается этот update? Да, этот вариант я рассматривал, и если ничего другого не придумаю, видимо буду делать именно так. Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо за подробное изложение! Просто для уточнения - я вам назвал два варианта. Второй - иметь у сцены флаг "активна", и соответственно итерировать как и сейчас полный реестр, а рисовать только ту сцену у которой этот флаг стоит. Точно так же как у вас наверное есть флаги типа "ОбъектВиденКамере" и вы по ним делаете какие-то действия типа "ПосчитатьКостиДляАнимации", а если не виден - расчет анимации для отрисовки пропускаете.

Comment: Да, точно с флагом тоже вариант годный кажется!